# continue loop after socket error

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using a python loop for finding open ports. The way it should work is if a port from my list is open and accepting a tcp connection, it will send me a response and if not it will skip to the next port number.

The problem I'm having is if the first port isn't responding, I receive an error from socket and the loop stops. Here's the script including how my ports list is defined.

```
import numpy;
import socket;
import sys;

with open("ports.ls") as f:
    ports = f.read().split(",");

portslist = []
for i in ports:
    portslist.append(i.strip());

portslist = [int(i) for i in portslist]

for i in portslist:
    target_host = sys.argv[1];
    target_port = i;
    print "[*] port:%d" % target_port;
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
    client.connect((target_host, i));
    client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n" % target_host);
    response = client.recv(4096);
    print response;
```

and the error I get is

```
socket.error: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

How do I continue the loop to the next iteration despite the first port not being responsive?

Comment: Can you use a `try` statement?

Comment: Do you get just that line or a stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that was a exception raised in this script and not passed back from the remote server, you can just add an exception handler.

...and get rid of the semicolons!

```
import numpy
import socket
import sys

with open("ports.ls") as f:
    ports = f.read().split(",")

portslist = []
for i in ports:
    portslist.append(i.strip())

portslist = [int(i) for i in portslist]

for i in portslist:
    target_host = sys.argv[1]
    target_port = i
    print "[*] port:%d" % target_port
    try:
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.connect((target_host, i))
        client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n" % target_host)
        response = client.recv(4096)
        print response
    except socket.error as e:
        print e
```

Comment: Thank you for that! As soon as that was fixed, the rest of what I wanted to implement was simple. And sorry about the semicolons, habit carried over from other languages.